# "is not registered in resolver" exception when serializing with abstract class using MessagePack

Tags: c#, serialization, msgpack

Trying to serialize `componentMappers` . The Exception is throwed at `.Serialize()`:

```
var componentMappers = new Bag<ComponentMapper>();
var componentMappersS = MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(componentMappers);
var componentMappersD = MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize<Bag<ComponentMapper>>(componentMappersS);
```

```
FormatterNotRegisteredException: MonoGame.Extended.Entities.ComponentMapper is not registered in resolver: MessagePack.Resolvers.StandardResolver
```

```
[MessagePackObject]
    public abstract class ComponentMapper
    {
        [SerializationConstructor]
        protected ComponentMapper(int id, Type componentType)
        {
            Id = id;
            ComponentType = componentType;
        }

        [Key(0)]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Key(2)]
        public Type ComponentType { get; }
        public abstract bool Has(int entityId);
        public abstract void Delete(int entityId);
    }

    [MessagePackObject]
    public class ComponentMapper<T> : ComponentMapper
        where T : class
    {
        private readonly Action<int> _onCompositionChanged;
        
        // Custom
        [SerializationConstructor]
        public ComponentMapper(int id, Bag<T> components) : base(id, typeof(T))
        {
            Id = id;
            Components = components;
        }
    }
public class Bag<T> : IEnumerable<T>
    {
        [Key(0)]
        public T[] _items;
        [Key(1)]
        public bool _isPrimitive;

        [IgnoreMember]
        public int Capacity => _items.Length;
        [IgnoreMember]
        public bool IsEmpty => Count == 0;
        [IgnoreMember]
        public int Count { get; private set; }

        // Custom
        [SerializationConstructor]
        public Bag(T[] _items, bool _isPrimitive)
        {
            this._isPrimitive = _isPrimitive;
            this._items = _items;
        }
}
```

Though if serializing for a specific type, i.e.:

```
var componentMapper = new ComponentMapper<Human>(0, new Bag<Human>());
            var componentMapperS = MessagePackSerializer.Serialize(componentMapper);
            var componentMapperD = MessagePackSerializer.Deserialize<ComponentMapper<Human>>(componentMapperS);
```

there are no problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `ComponentMapper` is `abstract` so I have to use `MessagePack`s `Union`. MessagePack tried to serialize the abstract class but it didn't know what type is exactly "underneath it" so you have to mark possible candidates with `Union`.